# Make a program run in a terminal

Tags: command-line

What command should I give to make a program run in a (new) terminal window?

**Background:**  I want to add another right-click option to Peazip which will pass the selected par2 file to the (installed) program par2, but I want it to run in a terminal, rather than the in the background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a specific terminal emulator (e.g. `xterm`, `konsole`, `gnome-terminal`, etc.), just look for its command-line arguments.

For example, to run console utility `htop` in Konsole (KDE's default terminal), type:

```
konsole -e /bin/sh -c htop
```

(You may want to add `--hold` argument to prevent Konsole closing immediately after process stops.)

To be more detailed: the above command runs `konsole` which runs `/bin/sh` interpreter inside itself, and the interpreter runs `htop` command inside itself.

Arguments of most popular terminal emulators are pretty similar, try these:

```
xterm -e /bin/sh -c htop
```

```
lxterminal -e /bin/sh -c htop
```

```
xfce4-terminal -e "/bin/sh -c htop"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great. Is there a way of setting the new terminal window to show the command that has been passed to it?  In your example:

htop